# Oracle SQL - Get maximum (Max) price of Item from latest three GRN dates (Order By)

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have two tables in this scenario, `grn_item` table and `grn` table, I fetch following columns only with the query below.

```
select gi.item_no, g.grn_date, gi.price from grn_item gi
join grn g on gi.grn_no = g.grn_no
```

Sample Data:

```
ITEM NO | GRN Date  | Price
----------------------------------
IT00001 | 03-AUG-21 | 1.2
IT00001 | 01-JUN-21 | 5
IT00001 | 08-MAY-21 | 6
IT00001 | 19-MAR-21 | 7.2
IT00002 | 14-NOV-21 | 3.4
IT00002 | 08-OCT-21 | 1.7
IT00002 | 25-FEB-21 | 2.5
IT00003 | 08-MAY-21 | 4.3
IT00003 | 03-SEP-21 | 8.2
IT00003 | 15-JUL-21 | 0.4
IT00003 | 11-DEC-21 | 9.3
IT00003 | 22-SEP-21 | 10.2
```

my requirement is bit tricky, not sure if it can be achieved, it is to get the **Max price** of each `item_no` from the **latest three** `grn_date`'s.

Example :- following are the records with the latest `grn_date`s, for **IT00003**.
Out of those, maximum price is `10.2`

```
IT00003 | 03-SEP-21 | 8.2
IT00003 | 11-DEC-21 | 9.3
IT00003 | 22-SEP-21 | 10.2
```

So my expected results should look as below. `grn_date` needs not to be displayed, but I included it below to compare it with sample data above.

```
ITEM NO | GRN Date  | max(Price)
----------------------------------
IT00001 | 08-MAY-21 | 6
IT00002 | 14-NOV-21 | 3.4
IT00003 | 22-SEP-21 | 10.2
```

I am using Oracle DB so, I use something like this to get the expected. but no success, can this be done?

```
select * from (select * from (select gi.item_no, max(gi.price) 
from grn_item gi join grn g on gi.grn_no = g.grn_no 
order by g.grn_date desc) where rownum <= 3) group by gi.item_no
```

Comment: The dates you show in the expected output seem to neither be the earliest nor latest date for each item.  Please explain your logic here.

Comment: I added an explanation, please don't close the question thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your existing (intermediate) result, you can finish the query as follows:

alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-MON-rr';

```
with
  intermediate_result (item_no, grn_date, price) as (
    select 'IT00001', to_date('03-AUG-21'),  1.2 from dual union all
    select 'IT00001', to_date('01-JUN-21'),  5   from dual union all
    select 'IT00001', to_date('08-MAY-21'),  6   from dual union all
    select 'IT00001', to_date('19-MAR-21'),  7.2 from dual union all
    select 'IT00002', to_date('14-NOV-21'),  3.4 from dual union all
    select 'IT00002', to_date('08-OCT-21'),  1.7 from dual union all
    select 'IT00002', to_date('25-FEB-21'),  2.5 from dual union all
    select 'IT00003', to_date('08-MAY-21'),  4.3 from dual union all
    select 'IT00003', to_date('03-SEP-21'),  8.2 from dual union all
    select 'IT00003', to_date('15-JUL-21'),  0.4 from dual union all
    select 'IT00003', to_date('11-DEC-21'),  9.3 from dual union all
    select 'IT00003', to_date('22-SEP-21'), 10.2 from dual
  )
select item_no, max(price) as max_price_of_last_3
from   (
         select item_no, price,
                row_number() over (partition by item_no
                                   order by grn_date desc) as rn
         from   intermediate_result
       )
where  rn <= 3
group  by item_no
;

ITEM_NO MAX_PRICE_OF_LAST_3
------- -------------------
IT00001                   6
IT00002                 3.4
IT00003                10.2
```

This shows the idea, and it tests it on your "input" data.

It would be better to combine this with your existing query, to save some work. Not tested, but I think it should look like this:

```
select item_no, max(price) as max_price_of_last_3
from   (
         select gi.item_no, gi.price,
                row_number() over (partition by gi.item_no
                                   order by g.grn_date desc) as rn
         from   grn_item gi join grn g on gi.grn_no = g.grn_no
       )
where  rn <= 3
group  by item_no
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! was testing this and it provides the expected results. going to need some time to understand but nice work.. Thanks anyway!